# Text file is always blank

Tags: c#

I have made this timer class and when its end timer function is called it is supposed to write a text file however it only seems to create a blank file every time. any ideas why? i have checked and the date modified is always the time i last ran the function.

```
public class Timer100NanoSeconds
{
    long startTick;
    List<Tuple<string, long>> stepTicks;
    readonly string functionName;
    int timesRan;
    public Timer100NanoSeconds(string name)
    {
        functionName = name;
        StartNew();
    }

    public void StartNew()
    {
        timesRan = 0;
        startTick = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        stepTicks = new List<Tuple<string, long>>();
    }

    public void AddStep(string temp)
    {
        stepTicks.Add(new Tuple<string, long>(temp, DateTime.Now.Ticks));
    }
      public void counterForTimesRan(int ran)
    {
        timesRan = ran;
    }
    public void EndTimer()
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(functionName + ".txt"))
        {
            file.WriteLine("Ran " + timesRan + " Times");
            for (int i = 0; i < stepTicks.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    if (stepTicks[i].Item2 - startTick != 0)
                    {
                        file.WriteLine(("" + (stepTicks[i].Item2 - startTick)).PadLeft(15, ' ') + "   ,  " + stepTicks[i].Item1.Trim());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (stepTicks[i].Item2 - stepTicks[i - 1].Item2 != 0)
                    {
                        file.WriteLine(("" + (stepTicks[i].Item2 - stepTicks[i - 1].Item2)).PadLeft(15, ' ') + "   ,  " + stepTicks[i].Item1.Trim());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void EndTimer(bool showZero)
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(functionName + ".txt"))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < stepTicks.Count; i++)
            {
                if (showZero)
                {
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        file.WriteLine(("" + (stepTicks[i].Item2 - startTick)).PadLeft(15, ' ') + "   ,  " + stepTicks[i].Item1.Trim());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        file.WriteLine(("" + (stepTicks[i].Item2 - stepTicks[i - 1].Item2)).PadLeft(15, ' ') + "   ,  " + stepTicks[i].Item1.Trim());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        if (stepTicks[i].Item2 - startTick != 0)
                        {
                            file.WriteLine(("" + (stepTicks[i].Item2 - startTick)).PadLeft(15, ' ') + "   ,  " + stepTicks[i].Item1.Trim());
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (stepTicks[i].Item2 - stepTicks[i - 1].Item2 != 0)
                        {
                            file.WriteLine(("" + (stepTicks[i].Item2 - stepTicks[i - 1].Item2)).PadLeft(15, ' ') + "   ,  " + stepTicks[i].Item1.Trim());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you ever call `EndTimer()`?

Comment: Are you sure one of your `if` statements is getting hit?

Comment: Where is the code that is using the timer?  Does it call `EndTimer()`?

Comment: DateTime.Now.Ticks will NOT give 100 nanoseconds of resolution, [more like 15 milliseonds](http://www.nullskull.com/articles/20021111.asp) - use the Stopwatch class for precise timings.